# Metadata lost when editing videos, any fix?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm editing a 360 video in Blender and I found out when I render animation the exported video has no metadata, meaning when I play the video or upload the video, it does not register as a 360 video. I know there is software that inject metadata and fix this but I have 2 problems with that, when I have around 70~ video to edit it pile up! second, the injected data is random and I would like to keep the original data as it is needed for a stage later on.

Is there a fix or a Blender plugin that can help me with this? I know blender is not mainly a video editor but I enjoy using it and I would like to keep using it!

Thanks.